# What's the best way to embed initial data into my ReactNative app using Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a ReactNative app using Firebase Firestore.

But I want my app to have some initial content as soon as the app is opened for the first time, even if the user has no internet connection.

I know that one way to do it is to fetch the content at build time and embed it in a JSON file that will be read by the app when it's first launched and I can write down the initial content into Firestore using batch write before the initial render (or at least keep showing the splash screen while I'm on it).

I wonder if there's a better of doing that, maybe something recommended by Google or the community, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support any notion of initial state or database contents, nor does it support writing to cache in such a way that the written data does not attempt to synchronized with the server.  What you're trying to do can only be implemented by packaging the initial data by some other means, and checking to see if that data should be queried before Firestore.